# HTML and CSS positioning changes with and without text

Tags: html, css

I have a code and there are some crazy things happening as a result of my code.
For example, I want to have three div boxes, I make them, style with CSS and when I write some text to the first, it goes down, if I write two lines of text to the second, the second one goes even lower and the third (without text) remains in good position, as I want.
 There is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.a   {

        background:;
        border:;
        box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #888888;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        border-radius:1px;
        display:inline-block;
        margin:10px;
        clear:both;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="a">
<a href="">Name</a><br>
123
</div>

<div class="a">
<a href="">Name</a>
</div>

<div class="a">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/q4Eg5/7/)**</kbd>

The three inside divs must be floated to the left so that they should align exactly. without floating, they can create problems in different browsers.

css

```
div.a {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #888888;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:1px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
```